# LXC not working in Centos 7

Tags: linux, lxc, centos7, cgroups

I am trying to setup lxc container in Centos 7. I have installed minimal Centos 7. And I have made sure cgconfig and cgred services are running. When I use lxc-attach command and go to lxc-container machine, even ls command is not working. I am not sure what am I missing.. Is there any way I can debug control group services are running fine? Or I am missing something else?

Thanks,

Vishnu Ganth

Comment: I amhaving this same issue. I installed lxc by following the steps from here:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-create-run-lxc-linux-containers-on-centos/

I am able to create containers using ubuntu  by using: lxc-create commands. But when I do: lxc-ls it just doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

I just solved, it seems that lxc-ls is not part of linux containers by default, It seems that you need extra packages, run:

```
yum whatprovides /usr/bin/lxc-ls
```

To check which packages are missing, then simply:

```
yum install package_name
```

In my case, it was:

```
yum install lxc-extra-1.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
```

Source: [BugZilla: RedHat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1103119)

cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with Ubuntu in LXC container. Some time ago i wanted to ask you if you found solution, but now i have about 50% of it.
Do the following after lxc-attach:

```
source /etc/environment
```

It will load `/etc/environment` file (only for the current session) which will update `$PATH` environment variable adding some missing paths. I can't find how this file should be loaded and which program handle this (bash or...?). You can add command above (`.` (dot) instead of `source` also works; they are synonyms) to your `.bashrc` or global rc file for bash.
Also all commands will work with their absolute path, `/bin/ls` for example.

Comment: Since this is not a full answer maybe it should be a comment instead.